# Detecting TFS version/install folder from MSBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I wish to call the [GetBuildProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399152(v=vs.100).aspx) task from my MSBuild script run on TFS. 
However, this script can be run on either TFS 2010 or TFS 2013.
Is there a way to detect the version of TFS that has launched an MSBuild Script? At the moment, I am getting around the problem like so:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CurrentProgramFiles>$(ProgramW6432)</CurrentProgramFiles>
    <CurrentProgramFiles Condition="$(CurrentProgramFiles) == ''">$(ProgramFiles)</CurrentProgramFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)!='' and Exists('$(CurrentProgramFiles)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010')">
    <TeamBuildRefPath>$(CurrentProgramFiles)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools</TeamBuildRefPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)!='' and Exists('$(CurrentProgramFiles)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0')">
    <TeamBuildRefPath>$(CurrentProgramFiles)\Microsoft Team="" Foundation Server 12.0\Tools</TeamBuildRefPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask
    TaskName="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.GetBuildProperties"
    AssemblyFile="$(TeamBuildRefPath)\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll"
    Condition="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)!=''" />
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you need the TFS version or the Build Agent version?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with TFS 2013 you have some interesting variables, not previously available [TF_BUILD environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx). So you can use TF_BUILD to know if you are using 2013, like this.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <IsTFS2013orHigher Condition="$(TF_BUILD)!=''>Yes</IsTFS2013orHigher>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

For the install path I would peek the Registry

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TFS2013InstallPath>$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\12.0@InstallPath)</TFS2013InstallPath>
    <TFS2012InstallPath>$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\11.0@InstallPath)</TFS2012InstallPath>
    <TFSInstallPath Condition="'$(TFS2013InstallPath)'!=''">$(TFS2013InstallPath)</TFSInstallPath>
    <TFSInstallPath Condition="'$(TFS2013InstallPath)'=='' and '$(TFS2012InstallPath)'!=''">$(TFS2012InstallPath)</TFSInstallPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: That will however only tell you which version of TF Build is present. You can connect TF Build 2010 to TFS 2013 so your results may vary.

Comment: Correct, but the Q was about detecting local install, i.e. the TFS Build Agent version, to use a specific MSBuild Task.

Comment: The question does not specify the Build Agent version, only TFS. I would prefer the person who asked the question to clarify rather than making assumptions. 

Comment: Yes, the agent will be the same as the server (i.e. can be a mix of TFS2010 and TFS2013)... so I wish to be able to tell which.

Thank you Giulio for your response, I think we cannot use the environment variables owing to support for older versions.

The registry peaking is a really neat idea though!

Comment: Since you check the xaml file into the server in question why not just add a variable that you set in the file or in the build definition?

Comment: That won't work for me as I am producing some MSBuild scripts for customers that can run various versions of TFS

Comment: Giulio Vian, grand mercy! Very usefull information about TF_BUILD* vars!