# Skip \ Run MSBuild Task depending on environment (manual VS vs TFS automated build)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

Is there any way to skip \ hide \ exclude custom task from TFS build?

Or even better, any way how to trigger some task just when building a project on a local machine (directly from VS)?

**SOLUTION**

I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604478/detecting-tfs-version-install-folder-from-msbuild).
The easiest way is to check for `$(TF_BUILD)` variable and to go from there to create a condition for your task. That way you can know if it's executed on TFS or not.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: It's azure TFS, so not sure what's the actual version number.